# how set code page to export xml file ion progress 4gl

Tags: xml, export, openedge, progress-4gl, 4gl

In the case when generating the xml I wanted to define the utf-16 code page when generating the file in the command:

```
hDoc: SAVE ("file", "c: \ tmp \ lantek.xml"). (export to utf-16)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an intermediate longchar variable which has had it's codepage fixed.

```
def var hxdoc   as handle.
def var hxn     as handle.
def var hxnt    as handle.
def var lcc     as longchar.

create x-document hxdoc.
create x-noderef hxn.
create x-noderef hxnt.

hxdoc:create-node( hxn, 'root', 'element' ).
hxdoc:append-child( hxn ).
hxdoc:create-node( hxnt, '', 'text' ).
hxn:append-child( hxnt ).

hxnt:node-value = 'røøt'.

fix-codepage( lcc ) = 'utf-16'. // remove to see difference

hxdoc:save( 'longchar', lcc ).

message 
    length( lcc, 'raw' ) skip
    string( lcc )
    .

copy-lob from lcc to file 'foobar.xml'. // you may need no-convert
```

When `fix-codepage` is not used, the length of the longchar is 42. When the codepage has been set to utf-16 the length of the longchar is 84.

Example at [abldojo.progress.com](https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=609e84589585066c21979915).